# Is there anyway to start a chat bot at a given waterfall path (instead of root) for web chat channel in MS Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I have a chatbot where I have created several waterfall dialogs that each have their own starting context.  I would like to be able to embed an iframe pointed to my bot, but tell it which one of these waterfalls to start at instead of "/".  Is that possible?

Comment: It is not possible to pass data in through the iframe. Can you provide more detail about the scenario you are trying to support?

Comment: basically I want a way to shortcut a user to some dialog path to start their interaction with my bot without starting at "/" (root).  The path to shortcut to is determined based on the current state of the app and where the user is within the app.  In essence if the user navigates to page "X" I want the bot there to present the "X" dialog.  Even something as simple as adding a query param to the IFrame embed URL that gets added to the session object the framework sends to my bot or something like that would be sufficient

Comment: now that the chat control is open source I have spent some time poking around it and the DirectLine api and I still don't see any obvious way of starting a conversation at any other path besides "root".  I do see a "serviceUrl" as part of the Activity schema but it isn't clear what this is used for

Comment: After looking further it looks like I will be able to use "channelData" to tell my bot which waterfall to serve on start...